# git allowing uncommitted changes to be visible in newly created feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I have created a file sample1 on master branch and edited it with a line "changes made to file in master". It was still untracked file as I did not add to git yet.

Then I created a branch using

> git checkout -b feature_branch

First thing I observed was the file sample1 was visible in the new feature_branch. I think this is ok.

Then I made changes to this file in the feature_branch.

I then went back to master branch using

> git checkout master

I opened the file and to my surprise, I see the changes made in feature branch in the master without me committing the changes or merging the files.

And then I made changes to the master again and switched to feature_branch and still found the changes.

Can anyone explain if this is intended behaviour?

Comment: git only does version control in files that were added to git via `add` and `commit`, otherwise git won't "take responsibility" over that file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modified files in a git branch are spilling over into another branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246275/modified-files-in-a-git-branch-are-spilling-over-into-another-branch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It was still untracked file as I did not add to git yet.

As long as the file is untracked (not in the index), you can switch branches (using nowodays the [new `git switch` command rather than the old `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)), the untracked file will remain there, untouched.

Any modification done on that file will not depend on your current branch.
See "[`git checkout` without deleting untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53345047/6309)" for more.